# Is there any way to convert from double to int in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to solve leetcode 172nd question using dart. Take the factorial of a given number and find how many zeros there are at the end.

I done until now

```
void main() {
  print(factorial(5));

}

factorial(int input) {
  int factorial = 1;
  var answer = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    factorial *= i;
  }

  while (factorial > 10 && factorial.toString().split('').last == "0") {
    factorial = (factorial / 10)

    answer++;
  }

  return answer;
}
```

but when i divide factorial by 10 it not allowed. and if assing at the begining like

```
double factorial=1;
```

this time the number is 120.0 and then zero is more. Can anyone help on this, thanks

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788320/how-to-convert-a-double-to-an-int-in-dart

Comment: This really should not be solved using string tests. Use the modulo operator and integer division instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use method for double to int;

```
double a = 8.5;
print(a.toInt())  // 8
```

Answer:

```html
 while (factorial > 10 && factorial.toString().split('').last == "0") {
    factorial = (factorial / 10).toInt(); // Add toInt()

    answer++;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert a double to int, just use:

```
double x = 1.256;
print(x.toInt()); //this will print 1
```

I am not sure what you are asking in this question other than this.

Comment: thansk it worked for me

Comment: Please mark an answer, whichever you want. You're welcome. Happy Coding !!

Comment: yes i am wating the time , you know that we have to wait 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Check the accepted answer to this Question: [How to do Integer division in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716978/how-to-do-integer-division-in-dart)

[Integer division](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html) in Dart has its own operator: `~/` as in

```
print(16 ~/ 3);
```