# how to convert double to int in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code like this

```
double total = 20.2;
int min = total as int;
```

flutter build was ok but it was exception on runtime.

I have tried int.parse() but it requires string not double.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to round the value :

```
double total = 20.2;
int min = total.round();
```

If you want to just truncate the value :

```
double total = 20.2;
int min = total.toInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

1. Using [**`toInt()`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toInt.html)
2. Using [**`truncate()`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/truncate.html)

   ```
   void main() {
      double d = 20.2;
    //using toInt();
      int a = d.toInt();
      print('Using toInt - $a');
    //   using truncate();
      int b = d.truncate();
      print('Using truncate - $b');
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate with [How to convert a double to an int in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788320/how-to-convert-a-double-to-an-int-in-dart)

In short, you can do that using `.toInt()`

```dart
double total = 20.2;
print(total.toInt());
```